# How to convert result of tweepy search to a JSON form

Tags: python, json, mongodb, twitter

I want to fetch tweets from twitter and save to my MongoDB database for which I am trying to convert the result to JSON.
This is my code

```
import tweepy
import json
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client=MongoClient()
db=client.scholarship

APP_KEY = app key here
APP_SECRET = app secret here
OAUTH_TOKEN = access-token here
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = token secret here

auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(APP_KEY,APP_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)

api=tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="scholarship",count=100,result_type="recent",include_entities=True,lang="en").items():
    tweet=json.dumps(tweet) 
    try: 
        db.daily.insert(tweet)
    except Exception as e:
        print "there is a problem ",e
    else:
        print "inserted"
```

I am getting an error
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

The reason being the return type of serach is of the form
(contributors=None, truncated=False, text=u'RT @AnwenAb: @OralRobertsU 2016 MedPro Rx Inc \ufffdEducation is Power\ufffd Scholarship Application Deadline June 1 2016', is_quote_status=False)

Need suggestions of what can be done here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it
Because your cursor doesn't return you a JSON. It returns instances of tweepy.models.Status model. And it obviously can't be parsed as JSON.

To get parsed JSON from the model you can use

```
tweet._json
```