# TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable") for a string with TextBlob

Tags: python, arrays, json, serialization, textblob

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38219889/how-to-convert-result-of-tweepy-search-to-a-json-form) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347743/typeerrorrepro-is-not-json-serializable-odoo-v8), but could not find something relevant to my issue. Pretty sure it's a general JSON-related question - not specific to TextBlob.

I'm trying to use TextBlob to analyse text parsed from a JSON response to an API. Here's a response that just does not seem to pass:

```
""Haiti r D, yes, due* no _ t iii me:nor.y;? 
In The 
in$i $ - 
active" E$icon-c arithms 
are applied to the rriinim ofverylar. database. 
"
```

This is just one of many. Does it have something to do with the characters in it - $ sign perhaps?

This is the error I keep getting:

```
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: TextBlob(""Haiti r D, yes, due* no _ t iii me:nor.y;? 
In The 
in$i $ - 
active" E$icon-c arithms 
are applied to the rriinim ofverylar. database. 
") is not JSON serializable
```

Any push in the right direction will be appreciated.